# Tkinter -- "window is not defined"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newbie in Python GUI's so I am using an online tutorial. When I run the following code, I get an error saying 'window' is not defined.

I am using a Windows PC with Windows 7 and Python 3.3 installed.

```
from tkinter import *

window.title("Test Window")

window.geometry('300x300')

window.wm_iconbitmap('Generals.ico') 
# Generals.ico is a filename for the window icon

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text='Label')
lbl.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you're following?

Answer (score 0):

your missing one line. You need to add `window = Tk()`

so your code should look like:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Test Window")
window.geometry('300x300')
window.wm_iconbitmap('Generals.ico') # Generals.ico is a filename for the window icon
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text='Label')
lbl.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Not sure if this is 100% correct cause I'm using python 2.7. You might not need to capitalive the 'T' in tk()